# Draw and rotate Text along a stroke

Tags: ios, objective-c, geometry, cgcontext

I try to rotate a text along a stroke. The user can create strokes by touch and move the finger in an direction he wants, the stroke then scales to the point where the finger is. I want to show the current length along the stroke and the text show stay scale and rotate with the stroke.

I think im not so far away from the working solution. Currently the text is not always at the right position, its depends on the rotation. I think there is something wrong with Context Translation, but lets see my code.

This is my method to draw the text:

```
- (void)drawText:(NSString *)text withFrame:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font rotation:(float)radians alignment:(NSTextAlignment)alignment context:(CGContextRef)context {
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
paragraphStyle.alignment = alignment;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font,
                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor] };

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, 1.0);
//CGRect textSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:rect.size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil];
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width * 0.5), rect.origin.y + (rect.size.height * 0.5));
CGContextRotateCTM(context, radians);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -(rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width * 0.5)), -(rect.origin.y + (rect.size.height * 0.5)));

[[UIColor redColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

[text drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

I call it like this:

```
CGFloat a = shapeToBeDrawn.startPoint.y - shapeToBeDrawn.endPoint.y;
CGFloat c = shapeToBeDrawn.length;
CGFloat alpha = -asin(a/c);

CGRect r = CGRectMake(shapeToBeDrawn.startPoint.x, shapeToBeDrawn.startPoint.y - 30, shapeToBeDrawn.endPoint.x - shapeToBeDrawn.startPoint.x, 20);
[self drawText:lengthStr withFrame:r withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0f] rotation:alpha alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter context:context];
```

There im calculation the angle alpha and pass the string i want to display. And also create the frame for the text above the frame of the shape.

Here a small video how it looks currently:

[Click](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42286315/Kapture%202017-01-23%20at%2011.57.38.mp4)

Hope someone can help me and my problem is clear. Thanks :)

Comment: And what code piece defines position for text output?

Comment: the code above the "drawText" method call. There i define a rect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate angle properly in all quadrants, use `atan2` function

```
alpha = atan2(endPoint.y - startPoint.y, endPoint.x - startPoint.x)
```

To define a rect -  calculate starting coordinates for rotated rectangle:

```
 x0 = startPoint.x + Sin(alpha) * 30   
 y0 = startPoint.y - Cos(alpha) * 30   
 rect.width =  shapeToBeDrawn.length
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't change anything.

Comment: I see in video that angle is completely wrong in 2,3 quadrants - atan2 using should correct this problem.

Comment: why "30"? Added your two improvements but it doesn't help. Text draw rect is now created this way: CGRect r = CGRectMake(shapeToBeDrawn.startPoint.x + sin(alpha) * 30, (shapeToBeDrawn.startPoint.y - cos(alpha) * 30) - 30, shapeToBeDrawn.endPoint.x - shapeToBeDrawn.startPoint.x, 20);

Comment: why "30" - because you have used shift 30.

Comment: the third argument - rectangle length? Change to stroke length. Additional `-30` is not needed, I think.

Comment: We are getting closer: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42286315/Kapture%202017-01-23%20at%2015.01.11.mp4

Comment: you should multiply  sin(alpha) by 30

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42286315/Kapture%202017-01-24%20at%209.06.41.mp4 now the last thing we need to remove is the gap that getting large when the stroke rotates. Thanks :)

Comment: It still looks strange - x for rect doesn't change until Pi/2. Could it be issue of float/integer/rounding? What units (radians or degrees) `atan2` returns and what units `sin/cos` uses?

Comment: Sorry, I have nor Mac, neither Obj-C. You would debug a bit - call calculation part with known arguments (to make angles 0, Pi/4, Pi/2 etc)  and log result X/Y values

Comment: Sorry, i dont come closer to the wanted result. Maybe you can check my log: http://pastebin.com/UKjXdaye If done a full 360° circle and logged all the values.

Comment: Logged values are OK. You can draw small circle at (x0,y0) to visually check. Perhaps I don't understand how rectangle (x0,y0,w,h,angle) is drawn relative to x0,y0